# How to initialize an DI injected class constructor before the HttpTrigger

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have an HTTP trigger Azure Function ("FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"). The function uses dependency injection, and one of the injected services is a class (FileFeedAlertProcessor) that needs to be initialized as soon as the application starts.

It seems that an HttpTrigger function will initialize all its injected services on the first call and not when the application starts. I'm struggling to find a way to build the services and get the service I want during the "Configure" method.

```cs
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<FileFeedAlertProcessor>();
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient<HttpClientService>()
            .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(builder => builder.WaitAndRetryAsync(new[]
        {
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
        }));

        // Initialize the constructor of FileFeedAlertProcessor before the HttpTrigger. 
        builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<FileFeedAlertProcessor>();

        // The above throws: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.IFileLoggingStatusManager'
        // while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Diagnostics.HostFileLoggerProvider'.'
    }
}
```

I'm able to solve this problem if I use "dotnet-insolated" function, because the HostBuilder class do have the option to build, but "dotnet-insolated" is not what I need.

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(s =>
    {
        s.AddSingleton<FileFeedAlertProcessor>();
        s.AddHttpClient<HttpClientService>()
            .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(builder => builder.WaitAndRetryAsync(new[]
            {
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
            }));
    }).Build();

// Starting the FileFeedAlertProcessor before function execution. 
host.Services.GetRequiredService<FileFeedAlertProcessor>().Start();

host.Run();
```

The trick I'm using is rather weird. I had to create a TimeTrigger function that runs once a year with RunOnStarup = true just to call FileFeedAlertProcessor service and initialize its constructor when the application starts.

```cs
public class FileFeedFunction
{
    private readonly FileFeedAlertProcessor _fileFeedAlertProcessor;
    public FileFeedFunction(FileFeedAlertProcessor fileFeedAlertProcessor)
    {
        _fileFeedAlertProcessor = fileFeedAlertProcessor;
    }

    // The purpose of this TimeTrigger function is to initialize the constructor of FileFeedAlertProcessor
    // every time the application is restarted. 
    [FunctionName("Starter")]
    public void Starter([TimerTrigger("0 0 1 1 *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        _fileFeedAlertProcessor.Start();
    }



    [FunctionName("FileFeed")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "{source}")] HttpRequest req, string source, ILogger log)
    {
        // Do other stuff
    }

}
```

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this, but is not well documented.

Comment: Even if you do not need isolated right now, please be adviced that going forwards from NET7 it will be the only way to do things so you might as well do it now

Comment: I do not suggest you to build service provider manually, you can register 'FileFeedAlertProcessor' with instance and start it at the end of 'Configure' method.

var instance = new FileFeedAlertProcessor();
s.AddSingleton<FileFeedAlertProcessor>(instance );